# Use template template parameter as return type of class function

Tags: c++, templates, c++14

I have created the following template struct where the second template parameter is a template template parameter. I would like to use it as return type of a function of sudden struct.

```
template<typename T, template<typename /*T*/, typename /*U*/> typename V>
struct MyStruct
{
   V myFunction();
}
```

I tried returning `V`, but it obviously doesn't work. I then tried returning `V<T, U>` but it doesn't work too. Should I declare the `U` parameter as the third template parameter of `MyStruct` or is there any other way to do what I want to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You re missing the argument list of `V`. However, you can't use `V<T, U> myFunction();` as you said. If you want to use `U` or anything else you need to add it. For example:

```
template<typename T, template<typename /*T*/, typename /*U*/> typename V, typename P>
struct MyStruct {
    V<T, P> myFunction();
};
```